# Power Automate: How to convert string to date format. Trying to import excel from OneDrive to SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, power-platform

I am trying to import excel file from OneDrive to SharePoint list using Power Automate. It is working as expected for all columns except the date column. I am not able to convert date string to date format. please help.

Comment: you will have to do something like this `formatDateTime(variables('DatumGesprek'),'MM-dd-yyyy')` but if you give more info like how is your date string and how do you expect result can help.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried this formula, but it didn't work. I would like to have format like this -  mm/dd/yyyy. Do you think there can be an issue because of the excel column format or variable data type? if yes, what should I data type I should use.

Comment: could you please show us how is your date string coming some screenshot  or something and then we can add some help, probably date as string is not correct and hence could not be converted

Comment: I am getting this output [{"@odata.etag":"","ItemInternalId":"2e271919-5bba-49a1-ba25-85db4f960065","Title":"1","StartDate":"44177"}]. 44177 is the date string. I want to convert this into date format.

Comment: alright and what does 44177 means/results into date, what should be it's output.
by the way string to date does not work like this.

Comment: 44177 is actually 12/12/2020 in the excel file. I need my date again in this format 12/12/2020.

Comment: I think I got your issue. Issue is w.r.t Excel. In your Excel column Start date has Format as Number. You will have to change format of your Start date as Date. This shall give you `{"@odata.etag":"","ItemInternalId":"2e271919-5bba-49a1-ba25-85db4f960065","Title":"1","StartDate":"12/12/2020"}]` let me know if this helps

Comment: I tried different formats of date columns in excel file, but every time in power automate I get the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read about the issue with Dates in Excel for Power Automate. Seems like this is know challenge and I myself tried steps from the blog and I could get to convert date as expected.

[Go through this blog and you will have an idea how to work with it.](https://www.shanebart.com/ms-flow-excel-dates/)

**Solution**

The root problem is that Microsoft Power Automate reads Date columns as Text. Excel stores dates in Serial Date format which means that a date like ‘2019-01-10' will be read as ‘43475' within Power Automate.

You can read more about how excel handles dates here:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm.

Therefore we need to convert the Number to a Date using the below expression within our Power Automate workflow

```
// Format
if(empty(<DATE TO CONVERT>),null,addDays('1899-12-30',int(<DATE TO CONVERT>),'yyyy-MM-dd'))
// Example
if(empty(item()?['Start Date']),null,addDays('1899-12-30',int(item()?['Start Date']),'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @AnkUser, finally with your help I was able to resolve my issue.

Comment: in same condition, if I have a date and time column and I want to move this from Excel of OneDrive to SharePoint list using Power Automate, what formula I have to use, please suggest.